# How else could this extension method to split a string into an array be parameterized?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

Here's a snippet I wrote to convert a comma list to an array of T:

```
public static T[] ToArray<T>(this string s, params char[] seps)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
    {
        return s.Split(seps.Length > 0 ? seps : new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Select(id => int.Parse(id))
                    .Cast<T>()
                    .ToArray();
    }
    else throw new Exception("cannot convert to " + typeof(T).Name);
}
```

I will need to put a case for each type I want to support.

Is there a better way to code this kind of thing?

Comment: well i've got decimals too... but your point is taken - i was just curious about alternate methods

Answer (score 4):

You can always do something like this:

```
public static T[] ToArray<T>(this string s, Func<string, T> converter, params char[] seps)
{
    return s.Split(seps.Length > 0 ? seps : new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(converter)
            .ToArray();
}
```

Which you can call like:

```
"1,2,3".ToArray(int.Parse, ',', ';');
```

I agree the .Parse is slightly ugly, but it gives you the flexibility of any data type you want...

Answer (score 2):

If you constrain `T` to `IConvertible`, you could use [ToType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.totype.aspx):

```
public static T[] ToArray<T>(this string s, params char[] seps)
   where T : IConvertible
{
    Type targetType = typeof(T);
    return s.Split(seps.Length > 0 ? seps : new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Cast<IConvertible>()
                    .Select(ic => ic.ToType(targetType, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                    .Cast<T>()
                    .ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
public static T[] ToArray<T>(this string s, Func<string, T> convert, char[] seps)
{
  char[] separators = seps != null && seps.Length > 0 ? seps : new[] { ',' };
  T[]    values     = s.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                       .Select(x => convert(x))
                       .ToArray()
                       ;
  return values;
}
```

Just pass in a delegate to do the conversion:

```
int[] Xs = "1,2,3".ToArray<int>(int.Parse , ',' , '-' , '/' , '|');
```